# How to fix an error "Resize medium operation for this format is not implemented yet"?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, vmware

I'm trying to increase disk size of my vmdk-file. Command line:

```
VBoxManage clonehd "source.vmdk" "cloned.vdi" --format vdi
```

Cloned.vdi has been created successfully (45.2Gb). But then I'm writing:

```
VBoxManage modifyhd "cloned.vdi" --resize 60200
```

And get an error

```
Progress state: VBOX_E_NOT_SUPPORTED
VBoxManage.exe: error: Resize medium operation for this format is not implemented yet!
```

Ok, I'm opening my VM VirtualBox Machine Setting -> Storage -> Adds hard disk -> Cloned.VDI.

On the right in the information section  I have:
Type(format): Normal (VMDK).
It's ok? How to fix this error? I have free 110Gb of ROM on my disk

Comment: anybody please?

Answer (score 21):

You need to do it like this:

1. VBoxManage clonehd [old.vmdk] [new-VDI]
2. VBoxManage modifyhd [new-VDI] --resize [60000]
3. VBoxManage clonehd [new-VDI] [newnew-VDI] --variant Fixed

Comment: Should [VDI] in step 2 not be [newVDI]?

Comment: what was the mistake he did ?

Comment: Please note that I have found that it is important to add the format vdi flag to step 1: `VBoxManage clonehd old.vmdk new.vdi --format vdi`

Comment: For future reference, it's shorter to do `vboxmanage createmedium <new> --size=<size> --format=VDI` `vboxmanage clonemedium <old> <new> --existing`. Either way, you then have to fiddle with the *.vbox file to replace the name and UUID of the old disk by the new one's, by editing the XML file. To get the UUID of a disk: `vboxmanage showhdinfo <file>`.

Comment: This approach in detail: https://www.inspekt.dev/2021/04/13/how-to-resize-virtualbox-hard-disk-vdi-file-virtualbox-resize-hard-disk-error-vbox_e_not_supported/

Answer (score 10):

Omid's answer is correct.

NOTE however that you can get pretty confusing "not supported for this version" error also in case your vdi-disk file has size 45GB on disk, but it is dynamic size disk with max size e.g. 80GB and your try to run

```
vboxmanage modifymedium vdi-disk-file-name --resize 60000
```

This is because you are actually trying to decrease the size, which virtualbox does not support for any format currently.

Comment: I had same problem and bingo! Your advice worked for me, thanks.

Comment: So, what is the solution in this case?

Comment: I haven't checked if it is nowadays possible to decrease virtualdisk, but at that time I added this answer, the only way to "decrease" virtual disk size is to clone it to smaller size disk.

Answer (score 0):

@omid answer is correct however if you already have virtual disk in .vdi format then you can still follow the three commands plus you have to go to virtual box->VM settings->storage->click on VM.vdi

On right side, you will get disk icon, just click on it and browse your new VDI that has been created after resizing(new-VDI or newnew-VDI in above case).